# Why is PHP saying that the value is not in the array when it is?

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax, wordpress

Thanks for taking a look at my question, I have developed a custom function in PHP to work with Ajax, I basically want to know if a value is in an array.

I'm checking if event_try is in the result set of a database query. In this case, 1004 is in the "$reg" array (I guarantee it), in which case the last if-else should return "notok" but I'm always getting "ok" from when I output the json with Ajax.

I've done tests with print_r and it does return "notok". It's just with the json and ajax for some reason.

**Here's the code:**

```
function validate_event_no_repeat(){

  // header('Content-type: application/json');
  $check_repeat_result = 0;
  $check_repeat = array();
  $event_try = 1004;

    global $wpdb;


    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    $get_attendee = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ATT_ID FROM su_esp_attendee_meta WHERE ATT_email='" . $current_user->user_email . "'");



      foreach ($get_attendee as $atte):
        $loggedID = $atte->ATT_ID;

        $registration = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ATT_ID, EVT_ID FROM su_esp_registration WHERE ATT_ID = $loggedID", ARRAY_N);

        foreach ($registration as $reg):
            if(in_array($event_try, $reg)):
              $check_repeat[] = "notok";
            else:
              $check_repeat[] = "ok";
            endif;
        endforeach;

      endforeach;

      if(in_array("notok", $check_repeat)):
        $check_repeat_result = "notok";
      else:
        $check_repeat_result = "ok";
      endif;

      echo json_encode(array('crr' => $check_repeat_result));

  die();
}
```

I know the above is *clearly* not done by a genius but it should work shouldn't it? I would appreciate any help I could get on this.

Comment: he's using ARRAY_N as an argument, I believe it yields a numeric array, hence his use of `in_array` without indexes (I'm gussing here)

Comment: Where do you expect `event_try`to be? in  `ATT_ID` or `EVT_ID` ?

Comment: @bub it's checking with EVT_ID

Comment: then you may check `if(in_array($event_try, $reg['EVT_ID']))`...

Comment: @bub doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `get_results` doesn't return an array of *arrays*, it returns an array of *objects*.

You can't use `in_array` to check objects, so first you need to turn the object into an array - you can do this simply by casting it, e.g.

```
    $registration = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ATT_ID, EVT_ID FROM su_esp_registration WHERE ATT_ID = $loggedID", ARRAY_N);

    foreach ($registration as $reg):

        /* ADD THIS LINE: */
        $reg_array = (array) $reg; /* cast the object as an array */

        if(in_array($event_try, $reg_array)):
          $check_repeat[] = "notok";
        else:
          $check_repeat[] = "ok";
        endif;
    endforeach;
```

Comment: I am returning it as a numerical array on the get_results with ARRAY_N... tried adding your suggestion though still returns "Ok". I think the problem is the last if-else check near die(). Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: @DavidMendienta How many rows does `get_results` return? I'd assumed it was only getting one...

Comment: As many as the user has relation to, it's a 1 to many relation, so it can return many rows.. for this particular user there's a row with EVT_ID 1004 which is the value I'm testing with... still PHP returns that it's not in the array.

Comment: I've tested the code myself (except using a different query obviously!) and it works perfectly. Have you done a `print_r($registration;` to see if there's anything at all unusual about the results?